# azure service bus - number of subscribers

Tags: service, azure, bus, subscriber

Is there some way that I can see the number of subscribers to my topic? And how many messages each subscriber has in its queue? And how many it has consumed?

If there is no monitoring solution for this today in azure, is there a way to do this programmatically?

thanks

Comment: Is this something you want to check from within your app, as a flow control choice, or as a monitoring/reporting function?

Comment: no, just need some monitoring tools for when things go wrong or something unexpected happens

Answer (score 0):

Check out AzureWatch, or one of the other 3rd parety monitoring tools. I know AzureWatch can monitor the length of many queues etc, do not know if it covers the service bus though. The developer is very responsive to feature requests though.